# JNI start jvm with unicode support

Tags: java, unicode, jvm, java-native-interface

I am using the invocation api to load and run a jvm within C code. I am using the java structure JavaVMOption to do this. In specific I am using its element
char *optionString
to specify my `-Dbs.prefsdir="c:\\develop\\XXXXChineseMixedLationCharsXXXX\\"`
where `bs.prefdir` is the path can be defined by user.

What I am doing is straight out of the java examples and it works fine right upto the point where I need to use a wide-character/unicode path - I can not do it, because optionString is a char* not a wchar_t*. Anybody know how to get around this? Solutions should be restricted to JDK 1.6 and lower.

I have read carefully JNI documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp633

```
char *optionString;  /* the option as a string in the default platform encoding */
```

I have read part of the eclipse executable launcher source code, there it did something like convert wide char to multibyte chars with default code page:

```
int byteCount = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, (wchar_t *)src, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char *dest = malloc(byteCount+1);
    dest[byteCount] = 0;
    WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, (wchar_t *)src, -1, dest, byteCount, NULL, NULL);
    return dest;
```

I have tried treating the optionString as a multibyte character string using the code above and this does not work. I have tried treating it as unicode itself, but this doesn't work either. Does anybody have a solution for this please?

Comment: Don’t know whether there’s a solution for the command line arguments. But since you want to specify a `-D` option only, you can use JNI to invoke `System.setProperty` to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the solution you proposed above, however, I do not know if user may set other parameters, bs.prefsdir is only an example, I need to support unicode in command line for other paramters as well. Eclipse launcher works fine. I do not know what is the magick in eclipse launcher? In most cases, I use eclipse launcher to start my app in executables, like eclipse executable. Sometimes, I need to start jvm and load it into in dotnet process, so that's why I need to pass and support unicode using JavaVMOption.

Comment: Maybe looking into the source code of the eclipse launcher helps.

Comment: @user3005398 Eclipse isn't calling JNI_CreateJavaVM; Its passing those arguments to the command line.  They aren't the same thing

Comment: Could you please detail a bit how roughly it works? Or some links on that? there seems to be less topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments passed to the JNI_CreateJavaVM are in the platform's default encoding, so I don't believe you will be able to pass a wide-byte character string into the JavaVMOption struct.

Try Holger's suggestion of setting the system property with a jstring of the proper encoding style, after creating the JVM.